# How to click based on image in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, bitmap, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium webdriver C# winform Firefox, how can I click an image from a document? Is this even possible?

Let me explain.

I have this image called ***watch.jpg*** on my desktop and I want it to find that image in the FireFox instance and click that image when it is visible. So, In this order

- Find Image
- Move to image
- Click Image

Thank you for your help.

I've tried this

```
        Bitmap Watch = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("Watch.jpg");
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.MoveToElement(Watch).Perform();
        action.Click().Perform();
```

Got These Errors

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions.MoveToElement(OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement)' has some invalid arguments 163
>
> Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement'    163

Comment: Show us the code you have tried to do it with so far, please. And how it worked?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible. `action.MoveToElement(Watch).Perform();` will take only webelement as its parameter. Intead `watch` is of type `Bitmap`, so you are getting the error `cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement'`.
You can search for a Image based automation tool in C# (I am not sure if it exists). If it were Java you could have used SIKULI. SIKULI is a image based tool automation tool which can take an image as input and locate it on screen and perform operations on it.

Hope this helps you.